# in for loop how to increment the row in data table

Tags: vb.net

in for loop how to increment to the next row and add a new member if the if condition is not met.

eg.

```
for i ...to ..row.count
 if condition to compare...if member exists then ....
( not Met ) 
increment the row in the data table and (goto)
else
( add a new member to a new row in datatable)
endif

next
```

Comment: see the example in msdn page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about looping over a different set - the rows in the datatable:

```
Dim i as Integer = 0
Dim row as DataRow
For Each row in myDataTable
    If (condition) Then
    'do something
    Else
    'something else
    End If
    'in case you need to keep a counter
    i = i + 1 
End
```

Comment: i want to increment the row when the the if condition is not met so that the new data gets stored in a new row

Comment: @sheron so you are trying to check a condition, and if not met add a new row of data? do you have some code you could post? It sounds like you may not need to iterate over the row collection at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understand; but I think....
You won't be able to use **For Each** to access the rows and modify the collection.

The most clear approach is to use a While Loop.

```
Dim i as Integer = 0 
While i < myDataTable.Rows.Count
    ' Your If statement here
End While
```

Comment: when i add a new record it gets added but when same record occurs again it does not compare and add to the same record but instead it creates a new record....can  anyone point out what is wrong